# IFF conditions for convergence in probability and almost surely

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory

I am working on a bunch of problems in preparation for an exam in Probability Theory.  I have come across two similar questions that I need some assistance with.

1. Suppose we have a sequence of events $\{ W_n \}$.  Let $m_n$ be the probability of these events.  I am trying to find the condition $C_1$ on $\{ m_n \}$ s.t ($C_1 \iff 1_{W_n} \rightarrow 0$ in probability).
2. Same question as before except now the events are independent and I am looking at a.s. convergence.

What I want help with is finding the conditions.  I think I can prove these problems if I have the condition.  So I am asking you to give me the conditions $C_1$ and $C_2$ and not how to prove those are the right conditions. I have tried a couple things which didn't work so that is why I am asking for your help.  Finally, I am also posting in the analysis section since these are analogous to a.e. convergence and convergence in measure. 
Thanks!

Comment: Really $C_1$ is easy... How does one write mathematically the condition that [$1_{W_n}\to0$ in probability]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $\chi_{W_n}\to 0$ in probability implies that $\mathbb P\{|\chi_{W_n}|>1/2\}\to 0$, hence $\mathbb P(W_n)\to 0$ for $n$ large enough.
2. Look at Borel-Cantelli's lemma.

Comment: For 1) does $P(W_n)$ need to equal $0$ for $n$ large enough or just converge to $0$?

Comment: To go to $0$, typo.

Comment: I'm stuck at a point.  I was able to prove 1.  For 2, I was able to also prove if the sum of the probabilities was finite then we had converge a.s. using B-C Lemma.  However, I can't figure out how to prove the converse.

Comment: By the way I still have not used independence in 2 so I must need to for the converse but not working so far.  Help would be appreciated.

Comment: never mind I used the contrapositive of the B-C Lemma part that uses independence.